# delete all numbers from third place in all lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How to delete all numbers from the 3th place? As place, I tried to refer from the third character at the line. In other words:

**Input**

```
a1 bcd3 efgh3029 2993
```

**Expected Output**

```
a1 bcd efgh
```

So far I have done with RE is: `s/.[0-9]//g`.

Comment: What does "from the 3th place" mean? Third field? Third character of every field? Third character on the line? Something else? Update your question to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @EdMorton update is done

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what it is you're trying to do, the text you have written to try to describe it is still highly ambiguous. good luck.

Comment: You are removing all number from the second fields, not the third, since you remove the `3` from `bcd3`.  -1 since question is unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
paste -d "" <(cut -c 1-2 input.txt) <(cut -c 3- input.txt | sed 's/[0-9]//g')
```

Comment: How creative you was and the answer is just perfect!!!! Thank so much for your time, helping me and have a good day : )

Comment: +1 for figuring out what was being asked for, but if that's what is asked for then all you need is one command `gawk '{print substr($0,1,2) gensub(/[0-9]/,"","g",substr($0,3))}' file` instead of 4 commands, a pipe, 2 process substitutions, and reading the file twice.

Comment: If performance is too bad, then you look for ways how to improve it. Otherwise I prefer clearer solution. And gensub is kind of unconventional function (not compliant with POSIX as much as I understand).

Comment: This is really a very inefficient way to solve a simple problem. Reading file twice and using so many binaries etc. See my awk command below to do this without gnu-awk

Comment: Same comment as Ed and anubhava. Reading the file several times in on command, and using lots of commands, makes this solution slow and inefficient. (-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in BASH itself:

```
s='a1 bcd3 efgh3029 2993'
p="${s:2}"
s="${s:0:2}${p//[0-9]/}"

echo "$s"
a1 bcd efgh
```

---

**EDIT** You can also do this using `awk` against a file

```
awk -v FS= '{printf "%s%s", $1, $2; p=substr($0, 3); gsub(/[[:digit:]]+/, "", p); 
    print p}' file
a1 bcd efgh
```

Comment: Thank so much for your proposal. I understand it as it is smoothly clear. But, How would it be to handle several similar lines?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(.{3}[^0-9]*)[0-9]+/\1/;ta' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed -r 's/.{3}/&\n/;h;s/[0-9]//g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/' file
```

EDIT:

The  first solution uses a loop to repeatedly remove numeric characters after the first three characters from the line. The `:a` is a loop place holder and following the substitution command the `ta` command jumps back to it on success

The second solution uses a "divide and conquer" method, where a copy of the original line is made and held in the hold space (HS), the original line then has all numeric characters removed and then the original and the copy are stitched back together using the first three characters from the original line and the remainder from the processes line.

Comment: Thank so much Potong. A last question, where can I learn to built my own codes like the second option? Thanks and have a good day : )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `awk` to solve the problem:

```
awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$i)}1' file
```

```
echo "a1 bcd3 efgh3029 2993" | awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$i)}1'
a1 bcd3 efgh
```

---

If to remove number from second field, do:

```
echo "a1 bcd3 efgh3029 2993" | awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$i)}1'
a1 bcd efgh
```

Answer (score -2):

```
echo 'a1 bcd3 efgh3029 2993' |sed -r 's/[0-9]+//g'
```

you will need -r (regexp-extended) option

Comment: mmmm nope... your propose delete all numbers from the beggining and I only want from the 3th place

Comment: sorry i havent seen i will fix it